# exit button not working properly..its moving to the before created activity

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public class Page3 extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView h,p;
Button z;
int highscore;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page3); 
Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit1);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
 }
```

now the exit button is given on activity 3,when the exit button is pressed its not exiting from the application .....its moving to the 2 activity page...why is it not exiting from application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
     public void onClick(View v)
    {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

to

```
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: (Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); \\is this leading to the homepage of our phone?

Comment: actually when i have given this code to goes to the home page but the application is not closing,do i need to add finish()

Answer (score 0):

To close application just call:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```